# Filter out data from jquery datatables based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have jquery datatable which contains the data pulled from database. By default there's no filtering and it has all the data necessary for that user. There's custom search in input fields in addition to jquery datatables own search. Now i'd like to implement a checkbox action where if checkbox is checked, data is filtered out based on element `data-attribute`.

This is the checkbox:

```
<div class='checkbox' id='subplayers'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' value=''>Show filtered content</label>
</div>"
```

The first column of the datatables is a `<td>` element with an attribute `data-insub=x` where `x is 1 || x is 0` (`<td data-insub='1'>` or `<td data-insub='0'>`).

In script i detect the checkbox change:

```
$('#subplayers').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        //Checked
        var playersInSub = document.querySelectorAll("[data-insub='1']");
    }
    else{
        //Not checked
    }     
});
```

Now i'd like to filter out all the players who have data-attribute `data-insub`set as `0` (keep the ones which have it as `1`). I think simple search is not sufficient here as this works on data written in table not on data attribute.

This is the PHP which is generating the table row data (more of an informative part of my code as i don't think it's relevant to the problem i'm having.).

```
$pid = $player['pid'];
$fname = $player['fname'];
$lname = $player['lname'];
$club = $player['club'];
$sameTourney = false;
if (in_array($pid, $playerIds)){
    $sameTourney = true;
}
$sameSub = false;
if (in_array($pid,$subPlayers)){
    $sameSub = true;
}
echo "<tr id='col+'".$playernumber."_filter'>";
    if ($sameSub){
        echo "<td class='playernumber' data-insub='1'>".$playernumber."</td>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<td class='playernumber' data-insub='0'>".$playernumber."</td>";
    }
    echo "<td class='firstnames'>".$fname."</td>";
    echo "<td class='lastnames'>".$lname."</td>";
    echo "<td class='clubnames'>".$club."</td>";
    if ($sameTourney){
        echo "<td><a href='#' class='modifyplayer' id='removeModify".$pid."' data-actiontype='remove' data-playerid='".$pid."'>Remove</a></td>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<td><a href='#' class='modifyplayer' id='addModify".$pid."' data-actiontype='add' data-playerid='".$pid."'>Add</a></td>";
    }

echo "</tr>";
$playernumber += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery **hide()** and **show()**

Hide all rows with attribute **data-insub="1"** use:

```
$("table").find("[data-insub='1']").hide();
```

Show all rows with attribute **data-insub="1"** use:

```
$("table").find("[data-insub='1']").show();
```

Comment: This would work if all the table elements are shown and the table entries are not on separate table pages (for example, if there are 25 elements in the table and 10 elements are shown per page, then there would be 3 pages - 10, 10 and 5 elements). Elements are hidden only from the first page.

Comment: Why not filter in the server side or send a json object back to client which will make life so much easy.

Answer (score 0):

As i couldn't find a way to do it with data attributes, i made classes for my rows - if i wish to filter it out i added class `allplayers` and if i wished it to stay i added class `insub`.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        var myRowClasses = oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr.className.split(" ");
        if($("#subplayers").is(":checked")) {
            return myRowClasses.indexOf('insub') > -1;
        }
        else{
            return myRowClasses.indexOf('allplayers') > -1;
        }

    });
```

The trick is that elements who have class `insub` need to have class `allplayers`as well.